# Передать в функцию экземпляр шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, классы, функции

У меня есть класс, и дружественная функция outer(...).

```
   template <unsigned int columns>
class Perceptron {
public:
    Perceptron(double norma, int flag, std::vector<std::tuple<int, bool>> function);
private:
auto net(int step) ->double;
auto f(double netParam)->bool;
auto learning(std::vector<std::tuple<int, bool>> & function, bool printOut)->bool;
auto step(int step)->void;
auto logisticFunction(double netParam)->double;

friend auto outer(const int& errors, const int& epochCount, const Perceptron<columns>* obj)->void;

int flag;
double norma;
std::vector<std::tuple<int, bool>> function;
std::vector<double> weights;


template <unsigned int columns>
auto Perceptron<columns>::learning(std::vector<std::tuple<int, bool>> & function, bool printOut)->bool {
    int epochCount = 0, errors = 1;

    while (errors != 0) {
        if (epochCount > 40) return false;

        errors = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pow(2, columns - 1); i++) {
            std::bitset<columns> bits(i + pow(2, columns - 1));
            if (std::get<1>(this->function[i]) != f(net(i)))
                errors++;
        }

        if (printOut)
            outer(errors, epochCount, this);


        for (int i = 0; i < this->function.size(); i++)
            this->step(i);

        epochCount++;
    }
    return true;
}

template <unsigned int columns>
auto outer(const int& errors, const int& epochCount, const Perceptron<columns>* obj)->void {
    std::cout << "Epocha " << epochCount << ":\nY = (";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < obj->function.size(); i++)
        std::cout << obj->f(obj->net(std::get<0>(obj->function[i]))) << ((i == (pow(2, columns - 1) - 1)) ? "),\n" : ",");
    std::cout << "W = (";
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        std::cout << obj->weights[i] << ((i == columns - 1) ? "), " : ",");
    std::cout << "E = " << errors << "\n";
}
```

Ошибка:

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl
>   outer(int,int,class Perceptron<5> *)"
>   (?outer@@YAXHHPAV?$Perceptron@$04@@@Z) в функции "private: bool
>   __thiscall Perceptron<5>::learning(class std::vector,class std::allocator >
>    &,bool)" (?learning@?$Perceptron@$04@@AAE_NAAV?$vector@V?$tuple@H_N@std@@V?$allocator@V?$tuple@H_N@std@@@2@@std@@_N@Z)   ITIB1   c:\Users\kudas\source\repos\ITIB1\ITIB1\ITIB1.obj   1

Comment: Во-первых, какую ошибку и где? Во-вторых, this - указатель, а функция принимает ссылку. `out(*this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то, вот так:

```
template<unsigned int col>
class A{
public:
    A(){ out(*this); };
    friend auto out(const A<col>& in){...};
};
```

Хотя формально до окончания конструктора объект `this` не является окончательно созданным :)

Но если у вас `out` шаблонный - то и объявлять его надо как шаблонный в самом классе:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

template<unsigned int col>
class A{
public:
    A(){ out(*this); };

    template<unsigned int c>
    friend void out(const A<c>&);
};

template<unsigned int c>
void out(const A<c>&)
{}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A<5> a;
    out(a);
}
```

Comment: да, это я для примера написал, на деле у меня из метода класса вызывается дружественная, но почему то теперь выдает : "ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ"

Comment: Покажите весь код (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: @Harry А теперь без смайликов поясните, с каких это пор объект внутри конструктора может быть не до конца создан? Не до конца инициализирован - да.

Comment: @gdb Объект - объект, а не выделенная память! - **создан**, когда он находится в корректном состоянии. Ваше "создан, но не до конца инициализирован" - примерно как автомобиль, который создан, но движок в него не поставлен, а вызов какой-то функции с передачей ему такого объекта - все равно что попытка покататься на таком автомобиле...

Comment: Вы дали нереальный код - с пропущенной закрывающей };, например. И наверчено у вас столько, что... Постарайтесь выбросить все лишнее, но не выбрасывать нужное - потому что **этот** код скомпилируется (после добавления `};`) - он же ничего не инстанцирует. Но если вы хотите определять друга вовне - то надо описать его как шаблон внутри класса - примерно так: https://ideone.com/aEXM0F